# NavigationView change ColorStateList only to one item on list

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

So with new Material Support Library google introduced NavigationView. It creates nav drawer using xml menu items with default colors black/primary_dark (unchecked/checked) I think. I found in the docs xml attributes to set color:

```
android.support.design:itemIconTint
android.support.design:itemTextColor
```

To change color state list of nav items, but it changes every item in NavigationView.
Did someone found a way to change color state list only for one item in new NavigationView?

Comment: You have to code in your custom adapter, to manage each item of NavigationView as your choice.

Comment: @krunalshah Do you have some code to demonstrate this? I don't think it's possible to use a custom adapter on NavigationView.